# Issue with carousel in modal using ngAnimate and angular-ui

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am updating this question to fit better the topic, looks like there's a conflict between Angular v1.4.8, Angular Animate 1.4.8 and Angular Bootstrap 0.14.3, after including ngAnimate as dependency this breaks the functionality of the carousel from the modal. you can see here  [updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YrSKylopmk6hs6eCrr5A?p=preview)

Have any anyone experienced a similar issue?

See the screenshots attached.
[image: local modal carousel]

This is my main.html

```
         <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="thumb in thumbs">
                       <img ng-src="{{thumb.image}}" alt="{{thumb.name}}" class="img-responsive" ng-click="open($index)" />
                    </div>
```

This is my modal gallery template:

```
<div class="modal-body">
          <div class="img-group">
            <uib-carousel>
              <uib-slide ng-repeat="thumb in thumbs" active="thumb.active">
                <img ng-src="{{thumb.image}}" alt="{{thumb.name}}" class="img-responsive pic" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">{{thumb.name}}</div>
              </uib-slide>
            </uib-carousel>
            <button type="button" class="close close-lg" ng-click="closeGallery()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is the JS from my main view ctrl

```
'use strict';

        angular.module('creativestudioApp')
            .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, Auth, $document, $uibModal, $timeout, socket) {

                $scope.thumbs = [{
                    "image": "https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/14501/screenshots/2362120/preview.jpg",
                    "name": "Cat on Fence"
                }, {
                    "image": "https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/193037/screenshots/876358/11q2.png",
                    "name": "Cat in Sun"
                }, {
                    "image": "https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/14501/screenshots/2362120/preview.jpg",
                    "name": "Blue Eyed Cat"
                }, {
                    "image": "https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/193037/screenshots/876358/11q2.png",
                    "name": "Patchy Cat"
                }, {
                    "image": "https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/14501/screenshots/2362120/preview.jpg",
                    "name": "Feral Cats"
                }, {
                    "image": "https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/193037/screenshots/876358/11q2.png",
                    "name": "Mad Cat"
                }, {
                    "image": "https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/14501/screenshots/2362120/preview.jpg",
                    "name": "Fluffy Cat"
                }, {
                    "image": "https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/193037/screenshots/876358/11q2.png",
                    "name": "Cat Laying Down"
                }];

                $scope.open = function(indx) {
                    console.log($scope.thumbs);
                    $scope.thumbs[indx].active = true;

                    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                        animation: true,
                        templateUrl: 'components/modal-gallery/modal-gallery.html',
                        controller: 'ModalGalleryCtrl',
                        resolve: {
                            thumbs: function() {
                                console.log('resolve', $scope.thumbs);
                                return $scope.thumbs;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                };

                $scope.closeGallery = function() {
                    $scope.modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };

            });
```

This is my gallery ctrl

```
angular.module('creativestudioApp')
          .controller('ModalGalleryCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, thumbs) {
            $scope.thumbs = thumbs;
            console.log('from modal ctrl', $scope.thumbs);
            $scope.closeGallery = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };

          });
```

Comment: Your `plnkr` links are invalid.

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr my bad, I updated the plnkrs.

Comment: Both Plunkers seem to work, unless I'm missing something. Can you add one where it doesn't work?

Comment: Are you sure that its not a css issue? Missing arrow images make me doubt about it.

Comment: It seems like `.carousel-inner>.item{display: none}`  is not applied to the elements.

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr I have the same css styles from plunker on my local machine, the only difference is that I am not using the default glyphicons from boostrap, thats why the broken arrows.

Comment: Don't you have some additional css styles?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr Default styles on my local are from twitter Boostrap 3.3.6 same as the plunker.

Comment: Ok, when you open modal for the first time, only one image is shown?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr The first time loads the image just fine, I can preview prev/next images with no issues, but after closing the modal and re-opening the modal, the current and previous images are showing up in the modal, like the image I uploaded, and every time time you close the modal it keeps appending the items to the modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97167/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-user1547007).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when directive is linked, `$destroy` method is not called, and `active` property on the slides is not being set to `false`. From the code you've provided, I can't figure out why it is happening, but you can try to set `false` value to `active` property in  an explicit way:

```
$scope.open = function(indx) {                    
    angular.forEach($scope.thumbs, function(e, k) {
        $scope.thumbs[k].active = false; 
    });
//...
```

Comment: Looks like there's a conflict between angular-1.4.8, angular-animate-1.4.8 and and angular bootstrap 0.14.3, the plunker demo didn't have it as dependency but I was including ng-animate as dependency on my local. this issue might not belong to this topic anymore. I will be updating the plunkers. Thank you so much Lazarev!